# Background music length and speed

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

For my Android app I would like background music. It doesn't have to go across activities so services do not matter.

Soundpool seems to stop playing the .ogg or .mp3 after about 6 seconds
MediaPlayer doesn't have the ability to change the speed (rate) of the music

What I would like to do is to allow the user to change the speed of the background music as it is playing. It would seem like SoundPool can do this but its hard to tell since it only plays for a few seconds.

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundPool is bad with wav files, with mp3 I didn't have problems...

```
    public final int play (int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume, int priority, int loop, float rate)
```

float rate - value of 0.5 means playback at half speed, can be 0.5-2.... I think you ought to use SoundPool... As for me, I appreciate Mediaplayer...

Comment: Do you know why the file might stop playing after 5-8 seconds? I have tried both mp3 and .ogg files.

Comment: So I figured out a solution. One can use SoundPool as long as the music clip is quite short (about 7 seconds) and have it loops. At that point the speed of the song can be changed. I'm still not sure how to do this for a longer piece of music but this solution will at least work for small game sound loops.

Comment: yeah, Soundpool is made for short effects in games... In my last app I use one mediaplayer for all mp3's, they interracts with release() and stop()... music mp3 plays for 20-30 sec... Maybe your mp3 are too high in quality? Look at their properties as a sond records and look for android UI opportunities...